# Failed to build gcld3 in Google Colab and Anaconda

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory

I typed the command:

```
!pip install gcld3
```

It shows following error:

```
Collecting gcld3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/73/72e469743a7e299e9a074857f7cac9f2b045bd495e20fdbd75cf081277c3/gcld3-3.0.13.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: gcld3
  Building wheel for gcld3 (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gcld3
  Running setup.py clean for gcld3
Failed to build gcld3
Installing collected packages: gcld3
    Running setup.py install for gcld3 ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-_lhh_qx8/gcld3/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-_lhh_qx8/gcld3/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-1iqkv3v8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried to find the `*.whl` file for `gcld3`, but I couldn't find it.